# Как реализованны указатели с++

Tags: c++, указатели, реализация

У меня возник вопрос, как реализован указатель и как он получает доступ к тому адресу который есть? Как при выполнении программы удается заполучить этот самый адрес, который в себе содержит указатель, он же не статичный, он не известен во время написания кода(если мы его вручную не задаем, но я не про это) и не известен во время компиляции (в некоторых случаях возможно известен, но я опять не про это). Что помогает программе его получить? P. s. есть ли источники с ответами на подобные вопросы, просто они стали меня довольно часто посещать, а каждый раз задавать их на форуме не совсем как мне кажется правильно с моей стороны. Заранее спасибо :)

Comment: Вам надо почитать что-то об устройстве компьютера, о программировании на ассемблере, тогда начнете понимать, что никакой магии в языках нет. Не знаю, подойдет ли (не помню, расписаны ли в этой книге основы), но можете попробовать прочесть ["Языки программирования: разработка и реализация"](https://www.ozon.ru/product/yazyki-programmirovaniya-razrabotka-i-realizatsiya-1158230/) (как обычно, в сети можно найти pdf)

Comment: Я заметил, что вы задаете интересные вопросы)

Comment: Вы про указатели в целом спрашиваете, или про указатели на функции?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, я спрашиваю про указатели в целом.

Comment: А разве указатели на функции не такие же указатели, как и все. (за исключением синтаксиса их объявления)

Comment: @ТарасПрогер, спасибо. Просто именно такие вопросы меня волнуют :)

Comment: Такие же, но механизмы вычисления адреса у разных вещей могут быть разные.

Comment: А спрашивать не стесняйтесь. Хорошие вопросы так же полезны для сайта, как и хорошие ответы, и у нас их в дефиците. Еще можете попробовать на англиском SO поспрашивать, у них квалификация намного выше (но и за правила они вахтерят сильнее).

Answer (score 5):

Фактически, указатель и получение доступа к кому адресу, куда указатель  указывает - это очень естественные для процессора и довольно "низкоуровневые" операции.

Они являются аналогами косвенной адресации, котрую Вы можете видеть в языке ассемблера.

И программа строится так, что в нужный момент указатель проинициализирован нужным адресом.

Можно даже сказать больше: выполнение программы строится "вокруг" адресов, котрые в процессе распределения памяти получают переменные.

" он же не статичный, он не известен во время написания кода" - да, но во время написания кода Вы и не оперируете с указателем, а оперируете с символически выражением, которое означает "указатель".

Есть еще один, трудоёмкий, но поучительный способ представить себе это: представьте, что вы - компилятор. Как бы Вы написали какую нибудь простую программу с указателями?

Если Ваш интерес простирается еще глубже - можно взять и разоборать простой пример компилятора С-подобного языка. Мне в этом смысле нравится то, что называется [SmallC](http://www.cpm.z80.de/small_c.html) (архив по первой ссылке) - весь компилятор состоит из четырех файлов, общим объемом около тысячи строк.

Еще есть так называемый "[Tiny C](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler)", очень известная штука, но, по моему мнению, он слишком сложный, чтобы в него "сесть и въехать".

В комментарриях подсказывают, что "нельзя понять работу компилятора не программируя на ассемблере". Я не думаю, что нужно прямо "программировать" на ассемблере, но поверхностное знакомство - что в процессоре есть регистры, вот такие то режимы обращения к памяти, и вот так то и так то можно выполнить какую то простую операцию - типа, цикл суммирования элементов массива - не помешали бы.

Comment: Пока ТС сам не начнет писать на асме, вряд ли он глубоко поймет эту тему

Answer (score 5):

> У меня возник вопрос, как реализован указатель

Указатель, это обычно просто число (или несколько чисел, тут все очень сильно зависит от платформы и процессора), которое хранится в памяти/регистре. На привычных Intel/AMD компьютерах это 64битное (8 байт) число. И ничего больше (да, тут вспомнят о том что и здесь есть сегментные регистры, и что не все биты используются, но обычному прикладному программисту о этом задумываться на ранних этапах не стоит)

На других платформах (на старых 16 битных интелах) это была пара с двух 16 битных чисел.

Я работал на Самсунговских контроллерах, где были разные типы указателей. Были 32битные для оперативной памяти для данных, были 16битные с флажками для кода, и ещё пара дополнительных типов. И смешивать их нельзя.

Можно представить себе указатель как библиотечный указатель на книгу в библиотеке. Если библиотека простая, то это будет просто 120 книга. А если это сложная библиотека, то это будет "2 корпус, 3 аудитория, 4 стеллаж, 6 ряд, 12 книга". Но если при этом находитесь уже в 3 аудитории, то адрес может быть сокращен.

Идем дальше.

> Что помогает программе его получить?

любой адрес получается так или иначе в результате каких то вычислений. К примеру, Вашей программе нужно немного памяти для массива. Она вызывает malloc и рантайм + ОС выделяют память и возвращают этот самый указатель. Да, программа его не знала, да, он не был известен до запуска программы, но он был вычислен. А вот как устроен менеджер памяти - это отдельная история. Но там тоже все построенно на вычислениях.

> что почитать.

Классику. Альфред В. Ахо - Компиляторы (книга с драконом) и Кнута, где то первый том.

Это сложные книги, поэтому, их нужно читать вначале как художественную литературу по диагонали пропуская сложные моменты. А потом через неделю-месяц возникнут вопросы и некое понимание и можно будет перечитать некоторые места детальнее.