# Как осуществляется доступ к локальным переменным?

Tags: c++, переменные, адрес

Мы знаем что при каждом вызове функций на стеке создаются локальные переменные(еще они могут помещаться в регистры, но сейчас меня мало это интересует). Т. к. каждый раз они создаются новые, то и адреса у них будут каждый раз разные(не всегда, но пусть будут разные). Как осуществляется доступ к этим самым переменным, если в машинном коде нет никаких имен, при этом у них, еще и разные адреса? Мне говорили, что для доступа к этим переменным используется структура описывающая объект. Если да, то как она имеет вид?

Comment: Конпилятор сам придумывает как разместить переменные, поэтому знает какие у них адреса.

Comment: если это примитивы то они складываются в стек, если сложный объект, то в стек кладётся указатель на него в памяти

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, так локальные переменные размещаются не на этапе компиляции, а во время вызовов функций, разве нет?

Comment: Вчера вы задали [вопрос про указатели](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1265875). В ответах к нему вам порекомендовали несколько хороших книг про архитектуру компьютера, устройство компиляторов и ассемблер. Неужели вы уже прочли их? Если нет, то самое время начать ;) Решать конечно вам, но многие из вопросов у вас отпадут сами собой.

Comment: Там есть такая фишка у проца - регистр, который указывает на текущий стек, вот к нему можно прибавить смещение и получаем адрес переменной.

Comment: @wololo, к сожалению у меня мало времени, чтоб их прочитать, а эта информация очень сильно мне сейчас нужна. Как будет время, я их обязательно прочту)

Comment: Поиграйте в https://gcc.godbolt.org/ там сразу будет видно что делает компиляторс (набирайте слева код функции, а справа будет то, что получает процессор на выполнение).

Comment: `к сожалению у меня мало времени, чтоб их прочитать, а эта информация очень сильно мне сейчас нужна` В последнее время вы задаёте довольно много вопросов на одну и ту же тематику (никто вам не запрещает это делать, я даже думаю, что для сайта это хорошо). Я просто хотел сказать, что быть может, прочтя одну толковую книгу, вы добьётесь результата _быстрее_, чем просто задавая вопросы вслепую?...

Comment: @wololo, хорошо, как будет время обязательно прочитаю книгу про устройство компилятора, не зря же мне ее порекомендовали)

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал "*Компиляторы*" Ахо-Ульмана-Сети-Рави, много вопросов окажутся отвеченными :) Но книга большая и толстая... А вообще - не забывайте, что есть, как ни странно, много не только компиляторов, но и аппаратных платформ, и одного общего ответа может просто не быть...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Представьте себе все локальные переменные (расположенные на стеке), как поля одной структуры, ассоциированной с функцией.

Смещения полей внутри структуры вычисляются на этапе компиляции.

Сама структура создается в момент вызова функции "магией компилятора", ее адрес - значение адреса верхушки стека на момент вызова функции.

Чтобы этот адрес не "убегал" при использовании стека внутри функции, он сохраняется в регистре процессора (если не путаю, то на x86 это регистр BP).

То есть во время работы функции адрес любой локальной переменной равен значению регистра, записанному на момент вызова функции + фиксированное смещение, вычисленное на этапе компиляции.