# Таблица идентификаторов с++

Tags: c++

Во время трансляции компилятор создаёт некоторую структуру данных, которая называется [таблица идентификаторов (символов)](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Так вот, насколько мне известно, в ней компилятор пишет смещения до разных объектов и возможно функций. Так вот у меня и возникает вопрос, какие идентификаторы туда попадают? Например, я знаю, что там точно есть глобальные переменные, а например локальные, их смещение тоже можно получить заранее, при помощи регистра хранящего их адрес и смещения, которое сделает компилятор. Хранятся ли локальные переменные в таблице, функции, поля класса и др. в таблице?

Comment: http://www.williamspublishing.com/Books/978-5-8459-1349-4.html

Comment: вопрос про сферического коня...

Comment: то, что автор вопроса показывает, это "список экспортируемых имен". Там есть глобальные переменные и функции. А вот локальные переменные  там быть не могут по определению.

Comment: @Harry, благодарю, то есть определение про `таблицу идентификаторов` не подходит или это совсем разные вещи?

Comment: Понимаете, это один из возможных вариантов написания компилятора. Можно и как-то иначе, так что говорить, что в компиляторе вообще таблица имен для глобальных - такая-то, для локальных - иная - это и есть то, что выше названо сферическим конем...

Comment: @KoVadim, я извиняюсь за тупой вопрос, но как называется такая же штука (список экспортируемых имён), но для локальных переменных?

Comment: если честно, то компилятор не генерирует их. Вы не можете обратится к переменной внутри функции, если эта функция "не выполняется в данный момент". Но даже так, у большинства переменных внутри функции нет постоянного адреса. Просто представьте себе рекурсию. Но может быть Вы ищите то, что называется "отладочной информацией"? - компилятор такое генерирует для того, что бы отладчик смог сопоставить код и бинарь

Comment: @KoVadim, вы правы, но разве локальным переменным во время компиляции не даётся определенное смещение, которое и помогает получить программе доступ к локальной переменной внутри стека? Информацию взял [отсюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1266269/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%83%D0%BF-%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC)

Comment: А это смещение по идее должно где-то лежать

Comment: Оно лежит прямо в коде. Может быть Вы скажете, что Вы хотите сделать?

Comment: @KoVadim, я хочу узнать как компилятор расставляет смещения для переменных и какие вспомогательные элементы при этом используются, сейчас попытаюсь разъяснить по подробнее.

Comment: В моём понимании, когда компилятор видит объявление некоторой переменной, то она заносится в некоторый список, в котором ей даётся определенное смещение. И при последующем обращении к этой переменной используется это смещение, которое как раз таки уже хранится в списке/таблице или какой-то другой структуре и мне как раз таки интересно, что это за структура

Comment: нет никакой "магической таблицы".  Компилятор просто вставляет относительные смещения прямо в сгенерированный бинарь.  Да, на момент компиляции где то такое может и существует внутри компиляторов, но в полученном бинарнике для локальных переменных этого уже нет

Comment: @KoVadim, мне бы хотелось подвести итог и закрепить, то что мы обговорили. Насколько я понял для глобальных переменных и функций существует некоторая структура(список экспортируемых имён), которая хранит в себе смещения и другую полезную информацию о них. При чем эту структуру можно представить в виде таблицы или чего-либо другого, главное, что она есть. Для локальных переменных существует что-то подобное. При чём обе эти структуры существуют только во время компиляции программы. И спасибо вам огромное, вы мне помогли:)

Comment: опять же, для глобальных переменных/функций она существует, если она нужна.

Comment: @KoVadim, а в каких случаях ее может не существовать?

Comment: Кстати, вы уверены что эта штука называется "список экспортируемых имён", просто по запросу в поисковике мне выдаёт совсем другую информацию

Comment: например, gcc делает все функции экспортируемыми и их список можно получить, а ms vc - нет.